How to align items across multiple rows considering variable item widths?
I'm trying to align a set of items across multiple rows in a container. Each item has a different width, and I want the layout to automatically adjust to fit the items neatly, filling each row as much as possible before wrapping to the next row. The maximum allowed items per row is 4.
The width of each item should be equal with the content width. The last item in row should have the width to be able to cover the rest of the space even if the content is not long.


.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allows items to wrap to the next row */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.item {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 20px); /* 4 items per row */
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Layout</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1 data is here, plrase askjd sadsad asd </div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2adm </div>
    <div class="item">Item 2 san. asmd. sada sdndsa m sad </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



In my situation the item with text Item 2adm should have the width equal with the content and the last item should fill the rest of the space, but in my scenario the width is 50/50.
How can I achieve the expected result?

Please dont add tags to the title. See MSE.

I think your problem is flex here, it seems to "overwrite" width as they are giving opposite instructions: Flex basically says get as wide as possible whereas width says get as small as possible. Also the CSS rules is applied to all items equally, there is no reason as to why items should have an asymmetric size.

@A-Tech, what is your suggestion here?

Here's the best I could come up with. You can use :last-of-type to say the last item will take up the remaining space. The existing items cannot grow, however, or you get into the original situation where both items grow and you end up 50/50 on that last row.
That last item also grows a bit too much, at least on Chrome Version 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit) where I'm testing. Your mileage may vary.


.container {
  --gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Allows items to wrap to the next row */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - var(--gap));
  /* 4 items per row */
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.item:last-of-type {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(75% - calc(var(--gap) * 2));
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Layout</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1 data is here, plrase askjd sadsad asd </div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2adm </div>
    <div class="item">Item 2 san. asmd. sada sdndsa m sad </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



In situations like this, I suggest using CSS Grid, as it seems purpose-built for this scenario:


.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.item {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.item:last-of-type {
   grid-column: 2/5;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Layout</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1 data is here, plrase askjd sadsad asd </div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2adm </div>
    <div class="item">Item 2 san. asmd. sada sdndsa m sad </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>




the nr of items is dynamic, they come from an API response, and the content length also could be different in every response. How to adopt this for this scenario?

That's a different question.

@ Heretic Monkey,  No, because in the question i added:  The last item in row should have the width to be able to cover the rest of the space even if the content is not long. - which means that every time when in a row are less than 4 items, the last items should automatically cover the rest space.

Well, you get what you pay for. You're getting free advice here.
